# MInecraft forge 1.7.10 won't show up in my profile options

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

So I downloaded forge and it's in my mods folder and everything, but when I go to make a new  folder for it it doesn't show up. I did have two other versions downloaded but they aren't in the mods folder. Those two are the ones that show up on the profile maker/editor.
Is it not showing up because there's already two there? Please help.

Comment: That's not how you install Forge. Go back to the install instructions and read them carefully.

Comment: what version of the Forge installer did you get? the .exe or the .jar. the .exe one is more automated which means you just have to run it, the .jar to my understanding is more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you install forge. Follow my steps carefully.

1. Download the version of Minecraft you wish to install Forge with.
2. Run that version of Minecraft and then close it.
3. Download the Forge installer and run it. If you wish to use it on a server, select server. If you wish to use it on a client (on your own game and not a server) then just click install.
4. After the installation, you should find a new profile in your Minecraft launcher called Forge, with the version you just installed already selected. Run it before you try to install any mods on it.
5. Once you've done that, you should find the mods folder in your .minecraft folder, you can put your mod jars here.

Here's where you went wrong: Forge creates that mods folder and you put the mods inside. You don't create the mods folder and put Forge inside.
Try again with my method, and good luck!

Comment: This typically works but I have run into cases where on some PCs the forge client installer will not add the profile to the launcher (permissions? dunno..) If this happens just go to launcher, add new profile, then choose the forge version from the list.. usually client installs OK even if it is unable to add the profile to the launcher for you.